# Get container sizes in Azure Blob Storage using Python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use `block_blob_service` library in Python in order to get the sizes of all containers in an Azure blob storage.
The following works, but takes too long (around 10 minutes for 50TB blob).

Is there a quicker way?

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=azureAccount, account_key=azurekey)
containers = block_blob_service.list_containers()
for c in containers:
        contName = c.name
        generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(contName)
        contSize = 0
        contNum = 0
        for blob in generator: 
            contSize += blob.properties.content_length
            contNum += 1
        print(contName + " : " + str(contSize/1000000) + " MB" + " in " + str(contNum) + " blobs")
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in AWS and GCP the equivalent way to do this is cloudwatch or the metrics service. I found this question looking to see if Azure has a similar call.

Comment: Check here for the metric: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage-reference#metrics

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the SDK, you can use [PowerShell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-size-powershell) or a [CLI script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-size-cli) to get container size.

Also , you can view the container size on the portal directly.

[image]

I think the main issue of executing so long is that the storage blobs are too fragmented to increase the number of loops, compared to the capacity of the storage blobs.

So , I suggest you put the calculation in  [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) to ease the pressure of your application.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try using this - but what I am looking for is a way to get the sizes of all the containers in the  account (e.g., for detecting the one that is taking too much storage space).

Comment: @teddiest Ok. I think Azure Function is a perfect option for you to loop the containers and detect the blobs which are larger than X MB.